# Automount EncFS unit

Tags: encryption, automounting, encfs, fedora

How can I automount an EncFS unit at login/start my session? I use Fedora 20 and KDE. Please don't mention apps like Cryptkeeper and so. I would rather console solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pam_mount.

Read step 5 in this mini [tutorial](http://pragmattica.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/encrypting-your-dropbox-seamlessly-and-automatically/) that walks you through it. Please note that there is a security issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pam http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/

Your encryption password must be the same as your login password